# Loading OpenGL functions on Linux - GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES vs glXGetProcAddress

Tags: linux, windows, opengl, driver

When I create a modern OpenGL context on Windows first I have to create a dummy context to get `wglCreateContextAttribsARB`. Then I use that function for creating the final context. My application has to link to `opengl32.lib/dll` which only contains OpenGL 1.2 functionality. When I want to use some modern OpenGL function, for example `glTexStorage2D` I have to use `wglGetProcAddress`.

I don't need a dummy context on Linux, I can just use `glXCreateContextAttribsARB`. My application links explicitly only to `libGL.so` and `libX11.so` (cmake - target_link_libraries). Apart from that, there is more differences. I have noticed that I don't have to use `glXGetProcAddress` at all when I want to use some modern OpenGL function. I can define `GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES` before include `glext.h` and then I can just use some modern OpenGL function. How does the application link to OpenGL function ? How does it work on Linux ? I also wonder if such mechanism has some drawbacks.

Let's assume that I don't define `GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES`. Can I just use `glXGetProcAddress` for getting function pointers like `wglGetProcAddress` on Windows or there are another differences ?

Comment: Some background: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Load_OpenGL_Functions